# What is going on when I set app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app) when running a Flask app on gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, gunicorn, werkzeug

I built a basic web app using Flask, and was able to run it from a virtual machine using its native http server. I quickly realized that with this set up, requests are blocking (I couldn't make concurrent requests for resources; any new request would wait until earlier requests had finished), and decided to try gunicorn to run the app to solve this problem. I followed the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/wsgi-standalone/), specifically running with this line:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 myproject:app
```

However, it failed to boot doing just this, and complained that there was no WSGI app. Poking around the internet, I found that a number of people had posted examples including the following:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

I added that, and it resolved my problem. I am confused though because this is apparently meant to solve a problem serving behind an HTTP proxy, but would the addition of gunicorn impose an HTTP proxy? Or was I always behind a proxy, and it just didn't matter for Flask's built-in server?

Also, [Werkzeug's documentation on Fixers](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/contrib/fixers/) warns "Do not use this middleware in non-proxy setups for security reasons." Considering the fix was clearly necessary, can I assume I'm on a proxy setup?

Comment: +1 - good question.  A question for you - were those two lines the *only* things you changed before you redeployed?

Comment: Yep. I tried a couple of other things first, but removed everything related to other attempts when they failed to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages from Gunicorn? ProxyFix just changes some environ variables so you get the correct details through a proxy. Also what version of Flask and Werkzeug are you using?

Comment: I'm surprised that gunicorn fails to boot without this. The only problems which are supposed to be solved by this fixer are related to reverse-proxying, e.g. when you get 127.0.0.1 as the client address because the request to gunicorn comes from nginx.

If you are interested in what the fixer actually does, i think the source is clear enough: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py#L94

Comment: You should probably inspect the gunicorn log file to see if there is a more detailed error message.  Also, if you are pointing to the wsgi_app object using a module path in some kind of config file, you should ensure that there's a reference to the wsgi_app as a top-level object in the module.  In your example, it looks like the wsgi_app is an attribute on some other object in the module, which might not allow it to be accessed via a module path, i.e. 'my_project.wsgi_module.app.wsgi_app' probably won't work but 'my_project.wsgi_module.app' would.  Might not be the issue but worth a look.

Comment: Are you actually accessing your web app at http://localhost:4000? It is common to run gunicorn behind another web server, like Apache or nginx, in reverse proxy mode. I'm still not sure why you'd need `ProxyFix` to even get gunicorn to start, though.

Answer (score 7):

A little late to the party, but [here (Flask v1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112004914/https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) is what the documentation says about ProxyFix.

[Documentation for v2](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/proxy_fix/)

To paraphrase: Deploying your server using gunicorn behind an HTTP proxy you will need to rewrite some of the headers so that the application can work.
And Werkzeug ships with a fixer that will solve some of the common setups.

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to show the code that defines your Flask application "app".

Where is "app" defined? Are you importing it from another file?

Here is my attempt to reproduce the issue:

```
$ cat myproject.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "ok"

$ bin/gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 myproject:app &
[1] 27435

2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27435] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27435] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4000 (27435)
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27435] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27441] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27441
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27442] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27442
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27445] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27445
2014-03-04 12:18:36 [27448] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27448

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:4000/
ok
```

As you can see it works fine. You definitely don't need ProxyFix in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that what you mean by "virtual machine using its native http server" is that you're running something like nginx as a reverse proxy/http server on the same VM, and then pointing it to `localhost:4000`. And that the error you were getting was similar to the `ModuleNotFoundError` [error in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213170/mod-wsgi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-app).  AND you're accessing the app from a different computer by going to the VM's IP address: you need to use ProxyFix, as nginx is acting as a (reverse) proxy server for the http requests, connecting to localhost, and then sending whatever it spits out to the client that hit nginx.

If you're not doing that, and your app has its own native http server, you can change how gunicorn is bound and set it to `-b 0.0.0.0:4000` to enable remote connections. This binds it to all available IP addresses, so if your VM has multiple it will respond on any of them if a request is sent to port 4000. If you only want it to listen on a specific address, you can enter that there instead. Setting `-b 127.0.0.1:4000` means that it will only listen to connections from `localhost` on port 4000, which makes it pretty useless as a webapp on a VM.

But if this is being exposed to the internet, you shouldn't do this. You should do the first thing.

The warning about not using the middleware if you're not using a proxy is applicable here. proxy_fix needs to know how many proxies are in front of it, so that it doesn't blindly trust headers that are being sent to it from potentially unwanted/malicious devices in the middle of your request and the gunicorn server serving that request. Setting the values provided to higher than the number of proxies in front of your gunicorn server also allows for faked headers to be passed to gunicorn as well. This probably isn't a problem in your case, but it is something you want to understand if you're going to put this app on the internet.